# Why is this function not firing?

Tags: javascript

I am working with the bing translate api and i have the following code

```
function translateali(){
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
          Microsoft.Translator.Widget.Translate('en', 'zh-cn', onProgress, onError, onComplete, onRestoreOriginal, 2000);
      }
  }
  function onProgress(value) {}
  function onError(error) {}
  function onComplete() {}
  function onRestoreOriginal() {}
}
translateali()
```

I am trying to bind the function to a onclick event which is why I wrapped it in a function but it doesnt do anything on click. However if I remove the function wrap like below it will work on page load

```
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
          Microsoft.Translator.Widget.Translate('en', 'zh-cn', onProgress, onError, onComplete, onRestoreOriginal, 2000);
      }
  }
  function onProgress(value) {}
  function onError(error) {}
  function onComplete() {}
  function onRestoreOriginal() {}
}
```

Comment: your functions are empty here

Comment: You may wish to define your function as: `translateali = function() {...}`.

Comment: You tagged this question with jQuery but are not using it. There is a shortcut in jQuery for document ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the listener, not the function.

Do the following:

```
function translateali() {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
      Microsoft.Translator.Widget.Translate('en', 'zh-cn', onProgress, onError, onComplete, onRestoreOriginal, 2000);
  }
}
```

So your button would look like this:

```
<button onclick="translateali()">Translate</button>
```